# Facebook sending one time notification

Tags: facebook, api, notifications

One of the core functions of an App i have been writing, is the ability to send someone a notification. Not from a user, but from the App.

I have successfully managed to send notifications to registered users of my app, that all works like a charm.

I also have the facebook API invitations working so users can invite their friends to use the app.

However, as opposed to most games, where two people use an app together (like songpop, etc), my App should not send notifications from a user that has been using the App. The user should not be known to the person that receives the notification. The initiative for sending a notification lies with the user though.

Documentation on this subject is quite scattered, and on one website it is explained that this functionality is available, while other sites say the opposite.

Is it possible, in any way, that my app can send a one time notification of ANY kind to a facebook user that has not yet authorized my app?

Edit:

Basically, the functionality i am looking for is that user A initiates a notification/message to user B (who is in his friends list), but User A stays anonymous to user B.

Comment: No, an invite is all you can send to a user that has not connected to your app yet.

Comment: The API is changed constantly, so the best thing to do is experiment and try to do what you're describing.  However, I'm pretty sure you can't do this as allowing apps to send notifications would certainly lead to spam.  I think you can send invites and/or requests, but not notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send notifications to users who have not authorized your app. The [documenation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) is quite clear on this:

```
Apps can send notifications to any existing user that has authorized the app.
```